# Pull value from checkbox and append to URL (multiple checkboxes with same class)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so here is the end goal.

In the end I will be working with multiple checkboxes that are going to be filtering results on a page. When a certain checkbox is checked it will append the value to the url.

Then I need to sort of do the opposite thing. If a user enters that specific URL it would change the default of that checkbox to checked.

I have the code working however I am not able to do it with specific checkboxes, it just continues to pull from the first value it finds. I know there is a better way than creating different click functions for every checkbox and running different statements for each, I just can't seem to figure that part out.

Here is what I have:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="business" class="myCheckbox" value="business" name="Industry"/> Business Communcations<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="construction" class="myCheckbox" value="construction" name="Industry"/> Construction<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="education" class="myCheckbox" value="education" name="Industry"/> Education<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="energy" class="myCheckbox" value="energy" name="Industry"/> Energy


  <script type="text/javascript">

    var url = location.search;

    var check = $(".myCheckbox");
    var checkValue = check.attr('value');
    var attr = $('.myCheckbox').attr('checked');

  // When checked, append value to URL

    $(".myCheckbox").click(function() {
      this.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
      if(typeof attr !== undefined && attr !== false){
      var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?' + checkValue;
      window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
    }

  });

  // Check if url = value for default checkmarks

      $(document).ready(function() {

        if (window.location.search == "?" + checkValue) {
            business.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
      }
  });

  </script>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: "multiple checkboxes with same id" **ids must be unique**  They are unique **id**entifiers.  Do not repeat them.  If you need a repeating identifier, use a class instead.

Comment: ^ @Taplar is completely correct. It's not to put you down at all, but _never ever ever ever ever_ use the same id more than once. There is no exception. Don't feel bad though, this comes up *a lot*. If I ever find out who or where seems to be teaching people otherwise I'm going to have a really heated talk with them ;)

Comment: It's not quite clear, but it looks you you want to be able pass in the url `?energy=false` and then have the `energy` checkbox unticked.  You're thinking that adding `id=energy` will be too much work.  If that's the case, then no need as you already have a way to find the checkbox:  `var opt = "energy";var val="true"; $("[value=" +  opt + "]").attr("checked", val);`  (can expand to a more detailed answer if this is the crux for the issue, so checking first).

Comment: You might like to revise your title/question - the title says checkbox-to-url but question is url-to-checkbox.  Then you add a 2nd question about changing the url, that would be better suited as a new question.

Comment: sorry I mean class, as you can see I do have unique id's, I think I will be better off trying to get one thing at a time for this. Will create a new question...thanks everyone